# Get current UIViews?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, object, uiview, methods

is there a way to get the current UIView object, which i defined in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

to use/change them in another method in the same .m file?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options. One is to store the UIView in a variable for later access. Another is to give the UIView a unique tag (`view.tag`) and grab it from its superview (`[containerView viewWithTag:tag]`).